# which phtml file should I edit to do with $_category?

Tags: category

getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
            drawItem($_category) ?>

The magento category display, I want to edit the categories tree code, but I do not now where.

For example, the categories code like this, I want to edit the class name. which file should I need to edit?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` (on Magento 1.9.0.1)

Method `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml`

The block is cached, so make sure to clean cache after your edits.

(also, do not directly edit this file, rewrite the block class and use OOP - there are many tutorials around: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/ )

Also, for next time, you can just turn on template-hints to see where the HTML comes from